# Facebook Signin in a mobile App (backed by a REST API)

Tags: java, ios, facebook, authentication

I have done some researching but I haven't find a clean explanation of how it all work.

I would like to know how does applicationa like Instagram, Wordcrack (online game), AirBnb and many other app have tier "Login with Facebook" done?

I currently work on the Java REST services that backups up an iOS app. 
If some one already has done a similar things in their app/server I would really appreciate some help

I'm not looking for ready to use code answer but more of a general idea of the architecture to achieve this.

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've done it in JavaScript, but the principle will surely be the same.
You have an API, provided by facebook. There are some information there : 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apis-and-sdks#third-party-sdks

And, more than that, you have declare your own app on facebook. This has, for me, 2 goals :

- provide the url of your server, so when you'll call facebook with the
  login information, he will know where to redirect
- specify the access your app need.

When i've begun to watch this, i've discovered satellizer. I think that's a good entry point to understand how it works with an example : 
https://github.com/sahat/satellizer

Hope this help.

Answer (score -1):

Supporting login through their website (Facebook,Twitter,Instagram etc) allows a user to use his already active profile to signup to a portal or an app. This way a user experience is enhanced and having to have separate login credentials for different apps and sites are reduced.

A developer utilizes the APIs or SDKs that these social networks expose to let you integrate it in your app and provide an easy sign up process to your users.